# Even after adding new mime type for Tika file is still detected as application/x-bplist

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-tika

I was trying to use Apache Tika to detect a `.memgraph` file exported out of Xcode. But the problem is that it was getting detected as `application/x-bplist` using the `Tika()` detector. So I created a new file `org/apache/tika/mime/custom-mimetypes.xml`and added the following to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info>
    <mime-type type="application/memgraph">
        <glob pattern="*.memgraph"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

But even after adding this the file was still getting detected as `application/x-bplist`. Will I have to write my own custom detector? And how will I go about writing one?

Comment: How did you add your custom mimetype file to the classpath? Did you try https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-MimeTypeMissing ?

Comment: I am using intellj and I have added the file in resources folder. I know it's in the right path as if I define custom type for a predefined file type, for example .docx, then it raises an exception that file type has been redefined.

Comment: Define it as a subtype of bplist - the memgraph format is based on the bplist format. Add `<sub-class-of type="application/x-bplist" />` to your mime entry

Comment: How to do that? Also, x-bplist corresponds to web downloaded files, so won't it give memgraph for all web downloaded files?

Comment: In your custom mimetypes file, inside the `<mime-type ...>` add the subclass line as well as the glob

Comment: What subclass line are you talking about?

Comment: See my comment above and/or https://github.com/apache/tika/commit/114009165410c91b57b91fc4eaddb089a8559451 !

Comment: Oh I saw it! Thanks a lot. But I have a follow up question. What exactly is x-bplist? And why does it correspond to *.webarchive?